# How to use Hibernate OData Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, odata, criteria, quarkus

I have some given environmental components

- Frontend (call enpoint with odata string $filter....)
- Backend (MariaDB)
- MiddleTier (Quarkus with normal rest endpoints)

I tried some OData Frameworks (Olingo, SDL OData Frameworks, odata4j), but always got different problems on compile (example olingo.: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE`) on all frameworks but with the same result: I can't use it.

So I created an endpoint:

```
@Path("/odata/v1.0/common/{entity}") //get the entity name
public Response OData(@PathParam(value = "entity") String entity, @Context HttpRequest req)

From reg -> req.getUri().getQueryParameters() i get the odata string ($filter ... & .....)
```

Is there a way to convert/interpret/parse it to hibernate query (with criteria) ?